# Slow down current animation?

Tags: android, animation

Im trying to achieve a fairly simple goal. There is an imageView of a propeller, with an infinite LinearInterpolator animation of spinning until a button is pressed. How to slow down the animation nicely to a halt after user presses the button?

Here is a very simple animation code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rotate
    android:interpolator="@anim/linear_interpolator"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:toDegrees="360"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:fillEnabled="true"
    android:duration="800" />
```

Comment: Have you made the animation in XML or in code? Upload your animation code

Comment: Now its in XML, however I start thinking its not possible to make a seamless transition between two xml animations.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Start animation:

```
int loops = 1000000;
int degreesPerSecond = 360;
view.animate().rotationBy(degreesPerSecond * loops).setDuration(loops * 1000)
  .setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
```

Stop animation:

```
view.animate().rotationBy(degreesPerSecond/2).setDuration(1000)
    .setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
```

You'll need to play with the values to get it how you want it. But this looks pretty good.

Comment: @VinayWadhwa It must be something to do with your exact setup or other stuff going on on the UI thread at that time. Suggest you ask your own question with the details or try it on it's own and make sure you use a real device.

Comment: what im doing is starting the animation at normal speed. On completion of some task, i stop the initial animation and play the second animation, as you suggested. Now, at that point lets say the initial animation stopped at 270 degrees. The next deacceleration animation would start from 0 degrees and hence the stutter/jump.. If the initial animation stops at 360 or 0 degrees by chance, we will not see the stutter

Comment: @VinayWadhwa Well you must have something different to what I have here. This works. It doesn't revert to 0 degrees.

Comment: @VinayWadhwa make sure you are using `rotationBy` and not just `rotation`

Answer (score 0):

Make another XML file with the same animation, and set the duration to more, maybe 1200. When you click the button you then set the of `View` (propeller) to the new slower animation.

```
public void onButtonClick(View v)
{
    if(slow){
        Animation fastRotate = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.rotate_fast); 
        propellerView.startAnimation(fastRotate)
    }
    else{
        Animation slowRotate = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.rotate_slow); 
        propellerView.startAnimation(slowRotate)
    }
}
```

Comment: Ive already tried that. However there is a significant jump between animations.

Comment: Is it because the proppeller goes back to "0"degress to start?